# 2D Cooley-Tukey FFT in Python

Tags: fourier-transform, python

I've been trying to confirm the process for the Cooley-Tukey approach for FFTs. Currently I have a  function that generates random input data for a matrix with $n_1$ rows and $n_2$ columns.
The result of my Cooley-Tukey approach is compared with a 1D FFT using the $\text{Scipy}$ package. My current approach is as follows:

1. Perform $n_1$ FFTs of length $n_2$
2. Transpose
3. Perform $n_2$ FFTs of length $n_1$

Below is my python program to test the pre-built functions against the Cooley-Tukey approach

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fft import fft
import math

class FFTOperations:
    def test(a, b):
        # matrix is n1 x n2, a is n1, b is n2
        np.random.seed(10)
        #generate random values to fill the matrix
        temp = []
        for i in range(a):
            row = []
            for k in range(b):
                row.append(np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0) + np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0)*1j)
            temp.append(row)
        #temp = [[1+0j,0+0j],[1+0j,0+0j]]
        cooley_tukey = np.array(temp)
        
        print('\nOriginal: \n' + str(cooley_tukey))
        
        #1st FFT
        for i in range(a):
            cooley_tukey[i] = fft(cooley_tukey[i],b)
        print('\n1st FFT: \n' + str(cooley_tukey))
        
        
        #Transpose the matrix
        cooley_tukey = cooley_tukey.transpose()
        print('\nTransposed: \n' + str(cooley_tukey))
        
        #2nd FFT
        for i in range(b):
            cooley_tukey[i] = fft(cooley_tukey[i],a)
        print('\n2nd FFT: \n' + str(cooley_tukey))
        #Reshape matrix for easier readability
        cooley_tukey = cooley_tukey.reshape([1,a*b])
        
        #Perform one large fft on entire dataset to comapre with Cooley-Tukey approach
        scipy_fft = np.array(temp)
        scipy_fft = scipy_fft.reshape([1,a*b])
        scipy_fft = fft(scipy_fft[0], a*b)
        print('\nCooley-Tukey: \n' + str(cooley_tukey[0]))
        print('\nScipy Package: \n' + str(scipy_fft))
        
b = FFTOperations
b.test(2,2)
```

Below is the output from executing the python code - currently I'm testing with a $3 \times 4$ matrix. The final two matrices shown are:

1. the  output of my attempt at Cooley-Tukey
2. the output of the python package.

```
Original: 
[[ 0.54264129-0.9584961j   0.26729647+0.49760777j]
 [-0.00298598-0.55040671j -0.60387427+0.52106142j]]

1st FFT: 
[[ 0.80993776-0.46088834j  0.27534482-1.45610387j]
 [-0.60686025-0.02934528j  0.6008883 -1.07146813j]]

Transposed: 
[[ 0.80993776-0.46088834j -0.60686025-0.02934528j]
 [ 0.27534482-1.45610387j  0.6008883 -1.07146813j]]

2nd FFT: 
[[ 0.20307751-0.49023362j  1.416798  -0.43154305j]
 [ 0.87623311-2.527572j   -0.32554348-0.38463573j]]

Cooley-Tukey: 
[ 0.20307751-0.49023362j  1.416798  -0.43154305j  0.87623311-2.527572j
 -0.32554348-0.38463573j]

Scipy Package: 
[0.20307751-0.49023362j 0.5221736 -1.27926013j 0.87623311-2.527572j
 0.56908092+0.46308135j]
```

Please let me know if you can spot an issue in my process.

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  Why do you do `2. Multiply by twiddle factors` and `3. Transpose` ? The 2D FFT just comprises the 1D FFT in one direction followed immediately by the 1D FFT in the other direction. There should be no need for extra twiddle factors or transposition.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the advice. I just updated the program and output on the post. I've been looking through a bunch of journal articles and research papers using a 4 step FFT approach and this was what I based my program off of. I changed up my code to remove the twiddle factor piece but I left the transpose in just to make the code easier for the FFT in the other direction. Despite making these changes I'm still running into issues. I tried a 2x2 matrix and found that the values were closer, with the 1st and 3rd elements matching exactly.

Comment: Yes, it looks like you need the transpose to do the FFT in the other direction (the way it's being applied).  Will try to have a look in more depth later.